# list of conversations and unread messages in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I´m building a chat app and this is the structure

```
/users
- aaa (...)
- bbb (...)
- ccc (---)

/conversations
- aaa-bbb
    1000000 {author: aaa, body: 'hello', read: false}
    1000001 {author: aaa, body: 'how are you', read: false}
- aaa-ccc
    1000002 {author: ccc, body: 'hello there', read: true}
```

basically I have a /users and /conversations. I store the conversation with the user1-user2 (where user1 id is < user2 id

this works fine. but want to do two more things

1. list all the conversations (with the last message sent to the conversation)
2. show a counter of unread messages (the read status is set by the message receiver not the sender)

to get all the conversations I´m involved (let´s assume current user is id: aaa)

```
database.ref("conversations").child(/* starts or ends with id aaa*/);
```

but for 2. I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: Do you want a count of unread messages per conversation or a count of people who have sent you messages that you haven't yet read? I would presume the latter is more useful.

Comment: Also, have you got your solution to your item 1. working?

Comment: nope. is just my idea because i dont know how to grab all conversations the user is involved. and for 2 I magine like an inbox where you see all the conversations and the count of messages that are not read (by the received) what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an additional node. You need a node that has a userid as the key and a list of users that they are conversing with. You maintain this node in parallel with when conversations are added or deleted. You can maintain an 'unread message count' on this node per userId but I recommend that you calculate it in the app by maintaining an 'unread message waiting' flag on each of the conversing users.
I have been down the road you have embarked on. There can be dead ends :-)

Update.

The third node could look like :

```
/activeConversations
    aaa
        bbb
            newMessage: true
        ccc
        fff
   bbb
        aaa
        ccc
        eee
    ccc
        aaa
        bbb
        ggg
```

Data duplication, reverse lists, flat structures are the norm in NoSQL dbs. Whatever it takes to make the data retrieval easiest. Storage is cheap, large nested structure downloads aren't and are usually difficult to process.
So this node tells you all the people aaa is talking to  with one simple read of the db and you can see aaa has a new message from bbb.

Update 2:

The key of your `conversations` node holds the ids of both participants so when you delete a conversation from that node you also delete the corresponding entries in the `activeConversations` node. You need the new node because this is the only way to easily retrieve all the conversations that eg. aaa is involved in. You cannot retrieve conversations that end with aaa directly in Firebase rtdb, you would have to retrieve the whole node and search the snapshot for the ones you want. If you have a lot of conversations that will be very expensive.

Comment: do you mean maintain a list of users, a list of conversations that a user is having and a list of of threads? can you show an example of what you´ve done? thx!

Comment: Did you decide if this helped you or not?

Comment: still trying to wrap my head around this. how to delete a conversation in this structure for example?